# Remove data in view with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

I have a view where collecting data in a form. The view is a JSP.

```js
$(".remove_field").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var nodeId = $(this).attr('data-remove-id');
  $(nodeId).remove();

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" border="0" align="middle">
  <c:if test="${empty rec}">
    <div id="lesiones" class="lesiones">
      <tr id="recurso_${loop.index}" class="itemResource" style="text-align:center">
        <td>
          <img src="gif/b.gif" width="5" height="1"><a href="#" class="detail-fixed botonLinkHab" cieDesc="idsCie[0]" cieDescShow="descripcionesCie_0" cieCode=""><img alt="<idioma:idiomaLiterales codLiteral='IML_F22A_35'/>" src="gif/lupa.gif" border="0" align="middle" width="16" height="16"></a>
        </td>
        <td width="100%">
          <input type="hidden" name="idsCie[0]" value="${requestScope.form.lesionId}" class="dinamic-input-text">
          <span><img src="gif/b.gif"><input height="16" width="16" type="text" name="descripcionesCie[0]" id="descripcionesCie_0" size="107" class="pruebaLU" value="${form.lesionId} - ${form.cie3NoG}"></span>
        </td>
        <td>
          <td width="16" height="16" align="center"><a href="#" class="remove_field">eliminar</a></td>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </div>
  </c:if>
</table>

<table id="containerResources">
  <c:forEach var="item" items="${rec}" varStatus="loop">
    <tr id="recurso_${loop.index}" class="itemResource" style="text-align:center">
      <td>
        <img src="gif/b.gif" width="5" height="1"><a href="#" class="detail botonLinkHab" cieDesc="idsCie[${loop.index}]" cieDescShow="descripcionesCie_${loop.index}" cieCode="${item.lesionId}"><img alt="<idioma:idiomaLiterales codLiteral='IML_F22A_35'/>" src="gif/lupa.gif" border="0" align="middle" width="16" height="16"></a>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="idsCie[${loop.index}]" value="${item.lesionId}" class="dinamic-input-text">
        <span><img src="gif/b.gif"><input height="16" width="16" type="text" name="descripcionesCie[${loop.index}]" id="descripcionesCie_${loop.index}" size="107" class="pruebaLU" value="${item.lesionId} - ${item.cie3NoG}"></span>
      </td>
      <td width="20" height="20">
        <button href="#" class="remove_field" data-remove-id="#recurso_${loop.index}"><img border="0" src="png/delete.png"/></button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </c:forEach>
</table>
```

This is correct and it delete elements of view but if add input dynamic and delete in the view, it appear in the value of the form.

What is the solution?

Comment: It looks like you didn't post what your form looks like.  My guess is your aren't deleting the associated field in your form.

Comment: "data-remove-id" is the field that I want delete.

Comment: what do you mean by adding input dynamically?  if you are adding new elements client side, and not reinitializing the click event, then it will probably do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

use `on` instead of `click`

```
$("#containerResources").on('click', '.remove_field', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var nodeId = $(this).attr('data-remove-id');
  $(nodeId).remove();
});
```

Comment: This is delete data of view but if add input dynamic, the data is in the form and return of view.

Comment: can you explain

Comment: The view of the question is the that use with java. I can delete input correct but if I add input dynamic of view and insert in database and I want delete it isn´t correct. This data is in the view. Sorry, I don´t speak english very well.